# plotting just a single rgb color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I am running matplotlib and I want to plot a single color, like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([(100, 100, 200)])
```

but this is showing a gradient. What is the issue?

Comment: You must have used it wrong: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Comment: @wwii Please be a bit friendlier.

Comment: lots of downvotes, delete  if you think it's not a good question for SO

Comment: I did not downvote (actually the opposite). But you can improve the quality of your question, for example, by adding the picture you get. This helps to show your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This gives only one color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([[(0, 0, 1)]])
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow([[(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)]])
```

[image]

You need a shape of MxNx3:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)]]).shape
(1, 1, 3)
```

Here M and N are 1.

> plt.imshow(X, ...)
>
> X : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)
>       Display the image in `X` to current axes.  `X` may be a float
>       array, a uint8 array or a PIL image. If `X` is an array, it
>       can have the following shapes:
>
> - MxN -- luminance (grayscale, float array only)
> - MxNx3 -- RGB (float or uint8 array)
> - MxNx4 -- RGBA (float or uint8 array)
>
>   The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays
>     should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0; MxN float arrays may be
>     normalized.

You need to convert int to float between `0` and `1`:

```
from __future__ import division  # needed for Python 2 only

plt.imshow([[(100 / 255, 100 / 255, 200 / 255)]])
```

[image]

Comment: So how do you convert 100 to a 0-1 range?

Comment: Divide the numbers by 255?

Comment: Great answer. I perused many threads for this seemingly easy question and only yours worked for me. Would you care to just explain the shape `(n, m)` part for me please? What are `n` and `m`? The RGB array I got looks like `color = array([214.75534938, 117.57921493, 122.02377125])`. I just don't understand why I have to use parenthesis around `color` in order to visualize it.

Comment: The array must be three-dimensional. The first two dimensions are zero. The extra parenthesis create these dimensions.